# Redirect URL with another URL in it

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

We sent out a newsletter, but in that newsletter a URL is wrong. It links to something like `https://www.example.com/page/https://www.example.com/page/page.html`.

Now we tried to redirect it like this:

```
Redirect 301 https://www.example.com/page/https://www.example.com/page/page.html https://www.example.com/page/page.html
```

But that did not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use this link to generate the 301 redirect https://www.rapidtables.com/web/tools/redirect-generator.html

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 /page/https://www.example.com/page/page.html https://www.example.com/page/page.html
```

See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html for additional docs.

Comment: That is what we tried, isn't it? It did not work unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^page/https(.*) /page/page.html [R=301,L]
```